# plotting boxplots that sort x axis by y value nested within a category in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Say I have a dataframe, `test`:

```
d1<-c(4.1,4.9,4.5,4.4,1.9,2.1,2.3,1.7,10.1,9.5,10.9,10.3,3.1,3.0,3.2,2.9)
d2<-c('a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','d','d','d','d')
d3<-c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)
test<-data.frame(d1,d2,d3)
```

if I make boxplots as a function of d2, I get the following figure:

```
plot(d1~d2,data=test)
```

[image: plot 1]

However, I would like to change two things about this plot:

(1) I want it to plot the two observations with the value of `0` in `d3` to plot first, and those with the value `1` to plot second.

(2) I want it to order the observations within each of these groups by the magnitude of the y value.

The correct final order would be a, c, b, d.

Bonus if you can add colors based on the `d3` variable.

Comment: what if you just add this `test$y <- with(test, ave(d1, d2, FUN = mean)); test <- test[with(test, order(d3, y)), ]; test$d2 <- with(test, factor(d2, levels = unique(d2)))` and then plot as you are now

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you coorectly, you can do this with `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(test, aes(x=reorder(d2,d3), y=d1, fill=factor(d3))) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

this gives:
[image]

You can do the same tric in base R:

```
plot(d1~reorder(d2,d3),data=test)
```

Comment: I'd like it to all be on one plot, rather two as you have done here. The order of the x axis would be a,c,b,d. I'd also prefer not to specify this manually, as the code is a simple example of something I need to scale to many more observations.

Comment: this works for this particular example, but does not scale. It does separate the observations according to the d3 parameter and colors them appropriately, but within each group specified by the d3 parameter they are not sorted by the mean d1 value for a group.